# How to find a database location on server using phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, database

I am pretty new to managing servers, right now I have trouble to find the location of our database. I see the DB in phpmyadmin, is there a way to find the real location using phpmyadmin ?

Running ubuntu 12.04 server

Answer (score 4):

First, get rid of phpMyAdmin. It's just a giant security hole, and doesn't even have a very pretty interface. You'll find that almost no *professional* DBAs or system administrators will go anywhere near it. It's not even really necessary, since the basics of SQL aren't hard to pick up.

Second, the database files themselves are in MySQL's `datadir`, so just check that in `/etc/my.cnf` or ask MySQL where it is.

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir';
```

Comment: I am using the PhpMyadmin only on my private virtual machine, of course I understand that this is a big security risk, but anyway I don't understand why my Question is downvoted without giving me some info why. I am learning.

Comment: You will have to ask the people who downvoted your question. I am not a mind reader!

Comment: Very good questions. I am an amateur server administrator. To be more exact, I am a businessman that manage my own server and write my own code. This question helps me a lot. But this place is full with snobbish full time server administrator that just look down to anyone that doesn't know the basic.